# I can't import certificate into Azure KeyVault

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I have purchased an App Service Certificate using Azure KeyVault following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-purchase-ssl-web-site).

But when I want to store the certificate in Azure Key Vault I get the following error:

[image]

This says that I am not an Active Directory Global Administrator but I used **svargasch1@hotmail.com** as username to create this account in Azure and in the portal this account is Account Admin:

[image]

> I have a BizSpark subscription

Comment: Do you choose an existing Key Vault to store this certificate or create new Key Vault?

Comment: Do you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071549/how-to-import-certificate-from-azure)?

Comment: @FredHan I want to create a new Key Vault.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT That answer does not help me. I want to create Key Vault for a web app.